# Azure Logic App - Authorization Issue

Tags: twitter-oauth, azure-logic-apps

In Azure Logic App, I added a Twitter connector, even after Authorizing the same, the Authorize button doesn't go away and I am not able to proceed.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Sajad,

Currently the default application associated with Logic Apps for Twitter is broken -- we are looking to fix it. In the meantime, if you associate the Twitter API App with your own Twitter App information (you can set one up for free), the logic app will run and authorize successfully. Here's some details on how you can do that. Let me know if you have any questions or issues, and apologies for the inconvenience

http://aka.ms/oauth_connectors